# SQL statement check IS NOT NULL before comparing two dates

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

Using `SQLite` and `JDBC` in `java netbeans`, executing through prepared statements,

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM product WHERE use_by_date < best_before_date";
```

I want to check that `use_by_date` in my table is null before executing this query is it possible? I need it to be null sometimes

EDIT: 
I have also tried

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM product WHERE use_by_date IS NULL OR use_by_date < before_date ;
```

When i try this it returns cost as 400 but the actual cost is 200? i can't understand why it does this.

Without use_by_date < before_date it returns 200 as total cost.
Also its not because there is more products being selected, I only have two products in there currently at 100 cost each

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen (or not happen) for `null` values?

Comment: for null values of use by date  i  want the product to be returned but i also want to add the constraint OR use_by_date < best_before_date;

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE use_by_date IS NULL OR use_by_date < best_before_date`?

Comment: And what was wrong with your 2nd version?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you're looking for something like

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM product WHERE "
    + "use_by_date is NULL OR use_by_date < best_before_date";
```